# Accessing/Setting Custom Text Properties of codebehind through XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Having some trouble getting my head around all the DP's i've recreated a very simple version of of my problem to try and sort out what the issue is. Alas, im still stumped..

I Have a custom userControl, and am attempting to set the properties of a textblock through the page that is instantiating that control. At the moment, in this version below, as a means of teaching myself im only trying to access a property from code behind.

The reason I wish to set custom text properties etc. is because I wish to have multiple versions of the control on the page with custom behaviour/text etc.

Here is my code behind.

```
 public partial class FeedbackCtrl : UserControl
{
    public bool IsFlagSet
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsFlagSetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsFlagSetProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFlagSetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsFlagSet", typeof(bool), typeof(FeedbackCtrl), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public FeedbackCtrl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

And my XAML..

```
<UserControl x:Class="Pipeline_General.Custom_Controls.FeedbackCtrl" x:Name="ThisCtrl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Expander HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Expander.Header Name="Header">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="NaN">
                <Border Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="gray" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
                        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#FFFF72D2" Text="{Binding Path=IsFlagSet}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Expander.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I do not understand your problem. The code above works, or?

Comment: it does? ok.. wierd.. it just isnt showing anything for me.... Should i not be seeing it in designer? this is what i was expecting. sorry if i am asking a stupid question

Comment: Your target is to set the IsFlagSet at WindowView? like: `<Window x:Class="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <scWpfApplication2:FeedbackCtrl IsFlagSet="True"></scWpfApplication2:FeedbackCtrl>
    </Grid>
</Window>`

Comment: ok fair enough if it works at runtime.. What I was really wanting though was to set in the designer, i was just using the above example to try and figure out DP's. The reason being is I need two instances of the user control.. with 2 textblocks and i was trying to do this efficiently without creating 2 different controls..